# Travis CI: BUILD FAILED with Rollout.io lib iOS

Tags: ios, travis-ci, rollout

I'm running command in Travis CI:

> set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -verbose -workspace APP_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme app_name -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release OBJROOT=$PWD/build SYMROOT=$PWD/build clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO | xcpretty

After compiling all files Travis writes:

> ▸ Running script 'Rollout.io post-build'
>   ** BUILD FAILED **
>   The following build commands failed:
>       PhaseScriptExecution Rollout.io\ post-build build/APP_NAME.build/Release-iphoneos/APP_NAME.build/Script-FBFA10E57CD7495E8662D829.sh
>   (1 failure)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This command runs well in Terminal and project builds well thought Xcode 7.2.1

Comment: Did you run the same command in your Terminal? Did you try it after a clean git clone?

Comment: Yes, I did it in Terminal. About clean git clone: but each time when I'm pushing to GitHub Travis pulls all changes.

Comment: I meant whether you tried it on your own Mac, after a clean git clone

Comment: @ViktorBenei, I see you. I've tried it. And It worked well. Now I have another problem:) How to sign .app file for getting .ipa? :)